# Errors occuring with Assets and Amazon S3

Tags: assets, s3

I've just set up a new S3 account and want to move my assets folders there. But when I try to upload a file, I get the following error:

```
S3::getObjectInfo(mikkelbang, shallowtree.png): [400] Unexpected HTTP status
```

And the same goes for when I try to update the Assets index:

```
S3::getBucket(): [InvalidRequest] The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported.
Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
```

I've never used S3 before, so it might be something I need to set up there. But I couldn't find any documentation on setting up S3 with Craft...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few regions that support only S3's v4 of signing requests without the possibility of falling back to v2.  The S3 library that Craft 2 uses only supports S3 v2. Check [this table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) for reference - if it says "Version 4 only" in the last column then that region can't be used in Craft 2.

We're not switching out that library in Craft 2.x, but it won't be a problem in Craft 3, so currently your best bet is to move your bucket to a different region, which also supports S3 v2 signing of requests (any other one, really).

Comment: Haha. Figures I managed to pick the only region that doesn't work. Changed to another region and it works now. Thanks.

Comment: @andris-sevcenko more than a year later and I still run into this problem. When will Frankfurt be supported?

Comment: @Florian the answer is still the same - Craft 3. It's not that simple to switch out a 3rd party lib, especially that complex, so this will definitely not happen in Craft 2.

Comment: So how's 3 coming along? ;)

Comment: @Florian haha, same deal as before - shooting for this year! ;)

Comment: Damm what a bummer ... unfortunately out of various reasons it's not an option for us to switch to another region :( Is there any manual workaround that we could apply?

Comment: Note, that this is also a problem with the new Ohio region.

Comment: I can confirm this is also a problem with the London region. Ireland is okay.

Comment: It would be helpful if this was mentioned in the Craft docs. Including some specific error logging (or validation when adding the assets config) would be even better still.