# Cannot access assets - unable to open image

Tags: craft2

I'm on Craft 2.7.8 and cannot access some of my assets - getting 
`Unable to open image ../html/assets/xxx.jpg` error all the time.

I've checked the owner, group and permissions dozen of times, currently everything set to root and 777.

I can access the images when I go directly to that URL in a browser, but for some reasons I cannot access them in a template.

In the Craft Admin Panel I changed the Source type to Amazon S3 bucket but that didn't work too. I can see the access/secret keys are correct (can display available buckets) but getting the same error "403 - unable to open".

Double checked with Postman and confirmed the images are there - looks like it's a Craft's or the Imager plugin issue.

Any ideas, please?
I'm using `html` as the root of my website (instead of `public`) and running on Apache.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was installing the [ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) package.

Regarding the S3 bucket - Craft 2 doesn't support my region (Frankfurt) - [read more here.](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14881/using-amazon-s3-with-craft-2-x-in-frankfurt-region)