# Can't find S3 bucket using Craft Pro in trial mode

Tags: s3

I am using the Craft Pro trial version and I want to use S3 for my Assets.  However, I enter my credentials but the refresh button does not show my bucket.  Also, when I try the refresh with wrong credentials it shows the error message but with correct it just doesn't show anything. I tried to connect to by bucket with other tools and was successful so this is why am thinking that is a restriction on the trial version of Pro.

So is it a Craft trial issue? Are you allowed to connect to S3 in trial version of Craft Pro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bucket you're trying to list is probably in the Frankfurt S3 region. The 3rd party library used in Craft 2.x for Amazon S3 support does not support Signature Version 4 that Frankfurt region requires, so you won't be able to use buckets in that region, as outlined [in this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5437/errors-occuring-with-assets-and-amazon-s3)

Craft 3.0 will not have this limitation, however.

Answer (score 2):

> So is it a Craft trial issue? Are you allowed to connect to S3 in trial version of Craft Pro?

Nope.  There are no limitations when running Craft on a ["non-public"](https://craftcms.com/support/license-enforcement#how-do-we-determine-craft-is-running-on-a-public-domain) domain in trial mode.

> However, I enter my credentials but the refresh button does not show my bucket.

Check your browser's console and see if it's logging any errors.  My guess is you'll see a 500 Internal Server Error and the underlying error message will be logged into `craft/storage/runtime/logs`.

Comment: Hmm , i don't really see any server errors in the console , probably it's the issue that @andris-sevcenko is saying. I'll try changing region for my bucket and see how it goes. thnx guys!!!